# jquery knob, animate and increment alpha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm using jquery [knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) with `.animate` as a percentage gauge which is working great however i'd like to set the opacity of the knob's canvas strokestyle to an alpha value as in: 0% = 0.1, 100% = 1 and have this increment with the animation so the stroke would start alpha 0 and end (in my example) at 0.7

I only have a cursory understanding of canvas but reviewing [the knob class](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/blob/master/js/jquery.knob.js), I've found that the strokestyle is set on ln 636:

```
c.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
```

I understand I can set this to an rgba value which i've tested and works, how could I increment the alpha value as described or is there a better solution?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bG478/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [pusher.color](http://tech.pusherhq.com/libraries/color) to grab the color and change it's alpha in the draw() function or the draw hook:

```
var color = pusher.color(current_color);
color.alpha(angle / 100);
```

You can now extract the modified color via:

```
color.html()
```

Here's an updated fiddle with (I think) the desired behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/bG478/2/

Answer (score 0):

Does using `rgba` not work for you?

```
var myColor = 'rgba(41,100,159,.5)';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bG478/1/

Comment: yes, but i'm looking to increment this alpha value with the animation so it's starts transparent and ends opaque. how could i do this?